# Recurrence Relation; unusual exercise (For me at least)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

I'm having some trouble with this reccurence problem.
Usually we have just one term like $2^n$ or $3n$, but this time there one of each kind. 
$$\begin{align}
a_{n}=5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2} + 2^n + 3n
\end{align}$$

A hint is to use when looking for the particular solution is to use the form:
$$\begin{align}
qn2^n + p_1n + p_2
\end{align}$$

I started with the homogenous solution, which is the easy part. I got 
$$\begin{align}
a_{n}^{(h)}=5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2} \implies&& r_1 = 2,&& r_2 = 3\\
a_n^{(h)} = \alpha_1 3^n + \alpha_2 2^n 
\end{align}$$
Then I tried with the particular solution (By using the hints form), but I got nowhere. Any reflections/pointers?

Comment: Some formatting tips: to write an inline formula, use `$formula$`; use `\implies` instead of `=>`; use `\cdot` (or nothing at all) instead of `*` to indicate multiplication.

Comment: Did you find $p_1$ and $p_2$?

Answer (score 0):

The original recurrence can be written as

\begin{equation}\label{a}
a_n-5a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2} = 2^n+3n.
\end{equation}

If you decrease indices of recurrence by one and multiply it by 2, you get

\begin{equation}
2a_{n-1}-10a_{n-2}+12a_{n-3} = 2^n+6n+6
\end{equation}

By substraction of latter recurence from the first you get

\begin{equation}
a_n-7a_{n-1}+16a_{n-2}-12a_{n-3} = -3n-6
\end{equation}

Decrease indices again and you get

\begin{equation}
a_{n-1}-7a_{n-2}+16a_{n-3}-12a_{n-4} = -3n-3
\end{equation}

Substract again and u will have

\begin{equation}
a_n-8a_{n-1}+23a_{n-2}-28a_{n-3} + 12a_{n-4}= -3
\end{equation}

And again decrease:

\begin{equation}
a_{n-1}-8a_{n-2}+23a_{n-3}-28a_{n-4} + 12a_{n-5}= -3
\end{equation}

and substract

\begin{equation}
a_n-9a_{n-1}+31a_{n-2}-51a_{n-3} + 40a_{n-4}-12a_{n-5}= 0
\end{equation}

Characteristic equation

\begin{equation}
x^5-9x^4+31x^3-51x^2+40x-12 = 0
\end{equation}

This equation has roots $x_1 = 1$ of multiplicity 2, $x_2=2$ of multiplicity 2, and $x_3 = 3$ of multiplicity 1.

So, the general solution of the recurrence is

\begin{equation}
a_n = C_1\cdot 1^n + C_2\cdot n\cdot 1^n + C_3\cdot 2^n + C_4\cdot n\cdot 2^n + C_5\cdot 3^n
\end{equation}

or

\begin{equation}
a_n = C_1 + C_2\cdot n + C_3\cdot 2^n + C_4\cdot n\cdot 2^n + C_5\cdot 3^n
\end{equation}